# Значение слова "предвкушение"

Tags: значение-слов, лексикография

В моем восприятии слово "предвкушение" несет смысл получения удовольствия от ожидания чего-то. Т. е. когда ты заранее в своем воображении переживаешь грядущее событие и непременно получаешь от этого удовольствие. Но вот пример определения из одного из словарей:"ПРЕДВКУШЕ́НИЕ, предвкушения, ср. (книжн.). Действие по гл. предвкусить-предвкушать; мысленное ощущение чего-нибудь заранее, предварительное переживание воображением чего-нибудь (ожидаемого). В предвкушении удовольствия.

Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940." В связи с этим возник вопрос. Всегда ли "предвкушение" обозначает именно приятные ожидания, переживания? Или могут быть и негативные переживания? Спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

> Предвкушение Ада, не дантовского, а самого настоящего, мои
>   соотечественники сполна пережили раньше, в те десятилетия, когда
>   “железный занавес” был до того плотным, что никакого вскрика отсюда
>   никто и нигде не услышит, а если даже чудом услышит и сочувственно
>   отзовется, уж до нас-то его сочувствие ни за что не дойдет. В сем и
>   состоит существо Ада, как со знанием дела разъяснял в свое время
>   собеседник Адриана Леверкюна (а также оруэлловский О'Брайен в
>   последней беседе с Уинстоном).

Сергей Аверинцев "[Верность здравомыслию](http://www.golubinski.ru/russia/aver/struve.htm)"

**Обновление**

Дополню [соседний ответ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/423702/180495) таким впечатлением:

Когда предвкушают плохое, то речь идёт о чём-то неотвратимом и скором, в непосредственной близости предстоящем. О том, что предстоит вот-вот принять и от чего нет возможности уклониться.

Негативное предвкушение усиливается, когда оставшееся до беды время сравнивают с чем-то более масштабным. Смерть в старости - с вечностью мира. Грядущее расставание - с долгой разлукой. Завершение дела, отношений или жизни - с тем, чего не успел сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Да ассоциативный ряд у глагола "предвкушать" - положительный. Определение Ушакова не опровергает это соображение, этот факт, положительная лексическая сочетаемость подразумевается, Ушаков такие вещи не отмечал.

Если вдруг в тексте адекватного автора встретится нечто подобное "предвкушению смерти", то это либо о стадальце, который устал жить и ждёт избавления, либо о члене клуба самоубийц.

А вот послевкусие может быть и горьким, но это уже "из другой оперы".